# Can the ES2020 nullish coalescing operator (??) be used to check undeclared variables?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2020

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

> The nullish coalescing operator (`??`) is a logical operator that returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is `null` or `undefined`, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

However, the following statement doesn't seem to work if the variable isn't declared:

```js
console.log(foobar ?? 555);
// Uncaught ReferenceError: foobar is not defined
```

If I explicitly declare the variable, it works:

```js
let foobar;
console.log(foobar ?? 555);
// 555
```

The only alternative appears to be:

```js
console.log(typeof foobar !== 'undefined' ? foobar : 555)
// 555
```

Is there a cleaner way to check if something is *undeclared* and return a fallback value?

I know there's an argument against why code would check for a variable that wouldn't be declared. For example, the following function accepts a parameter without assigning it a default value, making `??` seem useful:

```js
const baz = (foobar) => (`${foobar ?? 555}baz`) // same as: const baz = (foobar = 555) => (`${foobar}baz`);
baz()
// 555baz
```

Is this scenario the intended use of this operator? If it is, then also be served by assigning the argument a default value in the signature, so how does the nullish coalescing operator differ itself in usefulness?

***Note:** The statements above were run in Node.js 14 as well as Chrome 88.*

Comment: No, not really. Conditional operator is the way to go here. But dynamic variable names are quite a code smell and usually shouldn't be present in decently-maintained code anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's the argument I was referring to. The more I fleshed out the question, the more the answer became apparent.

Comment: You can use `globalThis.foobar ?? 555` or `window.foobar` in Chrome specifically.